# IOT based application submission process to AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Our app communicate with an external device  through TCP/IP Socket communication,How apple will review my app? Whether i need to send the device?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3):

Several possibilities:

1. You can make one of your external devices accessible thru a public
   internet IP address, and give Apple a demo account to use for their app review, and/or access instructions .
2. Or you can offer to ship them a device when they request one (Apple
   will tell you where, when and how, if needed).  Make sure your
   contact information is correct on the iTC app submission form.
3. Or you can add a demo mode to your app with a simulated external
   device, and give Apple review instructions on how to access/enable
   the simulated device mode.  (e.g. some radio apps have a built in
   fake radio station)
4. If your app can be seen as functional without the device, and the instructions on how it works with the device are adequate, it has been reported that Apple occasionally approves these apps without testing against the external device.  (e.g. some BLE apps maybe).